# $quote->setHasError(true) Not Working

Tags: php, magento, observers

I am using code from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33890/32082) to add an observer, get qty available from external source, and then set error true/false.

I have the observer set up correctly. I know this as it is doing everything I need it to, except show the fact that there are errors in the cart.

My code inside the observer (using `sales_quote_item_qty_set_after`) is:

```
public function cartQtyUpdated(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        if ($action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()) {

            /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();

            if ($item->dataHasChangedFor('qty')) {

                $qty        = (int)$item->getQty();
                $product_id = (int)$item->getProduct()->getId();

                /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

                $product_id = (int)$product->getEntityId();

                if ($product->getTypeId() == "configurable") {
                    $simple_id = (int)$item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')->getProduct()->getId();
                } else {
                    $simple_id = $product_id;
                }

                if (
                    $simple_id != '' &&
                    $qty != ''
                ) {

                    // Logic to get stock levels

                    if ($available['status'] == 'success') {

                        foreach ($options as $option) {
                            if ($option->getCode() == 'additional_options') {
                                $additional_options = unserialize($option->getvalue());
                                foreach ($additional_options as $key => $additional_option) {
                                    if ($additional_option['label'] == "Delivery Estimate") {
                                        $additional_options[$key]['value'] = $available['time'];
                                    }
                                }
                                $option->setValue(serialize($additional_options));
                            }
                        }
                        $item->setOptions($options)->save();
                        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
                    } else {

                        $item->getQuote()->setHasError(true);
                        $item->addErrorInfo(
                            'checkout',
                            1,
                            Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The requested Qty is not available.')
                        );
                        foreach ($options as $option) {
                            if ($option->getCode() == 'additional_options') {
                                $additional_options = unserialize($option->getvalue());
                                foreach ($additional_options as $key => $additional_option) {
                                    if ($additional_option['label'] == "Delivery Estimate") {
                                        $additional_options[$key]['value'] = "N/A";
                                    }
                                }
                                $option->setValue(serialize($additional_options));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The part that doesn't seem to be working is

```
$item->getQuote()->setHasError(true);
$item->addErrorInfo(
    'checkout',
    1,
    Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The requested Qty is not available.')
);
```

I am sure that I have had this working in the last couple of days but for some reason it just won't save the error.

When I put through a qty that I know is not available, and I know returns an the correct error, the cart buttons are still visible and there are no errors on the cart item.

I have added logs at the end of the above script and can safely say that the `setHasError()` method is doing it's job. Also, I added `Mage::log($item->getErrorInfos(), 7, 'cart.log', true);` which returns an array containing the exact error I am trying to set.

As everything seems to be setting properly, I am unsure as to why the cart is not showing the errors and why it seems to let me checkout.

Is there anything I can do to find where the errors are being lost between the observer and the cart reloading?

I feel like I'm talking to myself a bit here but here's an update:

**Update**

I have used `$item->getQuoteId()` to get the quote ID in the observer method and used

```
$session        = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote_id       = $session->getQuoteId();
```

To get the quote ID in the `cart.phtml` file. Both ID's are the same.

Could really do with some input on this guys and girls...